# tangent of a surface in a specific direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus

my question is where did "-xy" come from? in the first equation!
THank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$z-xy=0$ and $z=xy$. So when you factor in the change of $x$ and $y$ you get your equation. They take  $z=(x+\frac{h}{3})(y+\frac{2h}{3})$ then substituted this into $z-xy=0$.